# Why isn't `std::forward_as_tuple(1)` a constant expression?

Tags: c++, c++14, stdtuple

```
#include <tuple>

int main() {
  static_assert(std::is_same<std::tuple<int&&>,
                             decltype(std::forward_as_tuple(1))>::value, "");
  constexpr int x = 5;
  constexpr auto t1 = std::forward_as_tuple(1);  // (1)
  constexpr auto t2 = std::forward_as_tuple(x);  // (2)
  constexpr std::tuple<int&&> t3(1);             // (3)
  constexpr std::tuple<int> t4(1); // OK!
}
```

In the above code, that static_assert passes, however lines 1 through 3 fail to compile with both gcc 4.9 (supplied by ubuntu), and clang. They complain that the variables are not initialized by `constexprs`, that `x` is not a `constexpr` (even though it's initialized by a literal), that is creates a reference to a temporary or that their implementation of `forward_as_tuple()` is not (though the C++14 standard does guarantee this).

I'm working on some code that makes heavy use of `std::tuple` and `constexpr`. I can get around `std::forward_as_tuple()` not being defined as `constexpr`, but I can't understand why `forward_as_tuple(0)` would return a `tuple<int&&>`, which according to clang creates a reference to a temporary making it not constexpr. The alternatives don't work for what I need--`std::make_tuple()` can't be used for perfect forwarding and `std::tie` can't store literal values. **Edit:** Why does `std::forward_as_tuple()` work this way and without offering an alternative?

Am I doing something fundamentally wrong here or is there something I don't understand?

Comment: ... `forward_as_tuple` returns `std::tuple<Types&&...>`.  What type do you expect `forward_as_tuple(0)` to return?  What `Types...` is more right than `int`?  Ie, you have demonstrated what happens: what do you expect to happen (for each line).  It is for perfect forwarding: it returns a tuple of references or rvalue references.  One that stores rvalues can be written, and it isn't very long, if you want it.

Comment: You can't have `constexpr int&& var = ..`.

Comment: If I passed `std::forward_as_tuple(1,x,std::move(y))`, I would expect `std::tuple<int,X&,Y>`. What I don't understand is why `std::forward_as_tuple` thinks that `tuple<int&&, X& &&, Y&&>` is somehow more useful or correct and doesn't offer a version for which `forward_as_tuple` is valid on literals. In other words, it doesn't seem like `forward_as_tuple` is actually properly forwarding.

Comment: Because being able to name type does not mean it is legal to create an instance of that type.

Answer (score 0):

`std::forward_as_tuple` works that way because it's specified to return a tuple of references for perfect forwarding. If you want a function that returns `std::tuple<int,X&,Y>` when called with `1`, `x`, and `std::move(y)`, then write one:

```
template <typename...Ts>
constexpr std::tuple<Ts...> foo(Ts&&...ts) {
  return std::tuple<Ts...>{std::forward<Ts>(ts)...};
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/74c7401b7fcaa6c1)

Comment: Not sure if it's how I worded it, but this does not answer my question. So, if `t = std::forward_as_tuple(0, x)` would return an `std::tuple<int&&, X& &&>`, then `std::get<0>(t)` would return `int&&` and `std::get<1>(t)` would return an `X& &&`, and if passed to another function, they would be perfect forwarded. But wouldn't I get the same effect by `t = foo(0, x)` and `std::get<0>(std::move(t))`, `std::get<1>(std::move(t))`? Does that not also perfect-forward?